# How to set SwiftUI v2 (2020) InsetGroupedListStyle List's background color

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to set a List's background color; but it remains gray.

```
var body: some View {
        
        List {
            ForEach(...) {
                Section() {
                    Text("not the actual code")
                }
            }
        }
        .listStyle(InsetGroupedListStyle())
        .background(Color.red)
    }
```

`.listRowBackground(Color.green)` works for the row, but not the table's background color

Answer (score 1):

Use colorMultiply(Color:)

```
List {
        ForEach(...) {
            Section() {
                Text("not the actual code")
            }
        }
    }.colorMultiply(Color.green).padding(.top)
```

Comment: This sort-of works, but also affects the color of the row.